# Html.BeginForm inside list of partial views

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, data-binding

Is it possible to do Databinding on a form post when the form is inside a partial view - either through `<partial name=... for=...>` or `Html.EditorFor(...`, but where that partial view is inside a foreach block?

The user expects to only work with a subset of the page (it is a tabbed interface) and submit only the tab they are currently working with. Each tab is its own partial view and its own form. Each tab has an identical set of fields with a different primary key (included in the form as a hidden input).

My form submit handler is firing, but the databound object is empty.

My HTML ids are prefixed thanks to the `partial for` or `EditorFor`.

`[Bind(Prefix)]` on the form submit handler doesn't work for me because the prefix isn't constant, it depends on the loop iteration.

My current code:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.TabModels.Count(); i++)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.TabModels[i], "TabModel")
}
```

It does bind properly on display, just not on submit.

Is there a way to do this, or should I submit the entire `Model` instead of `Model.TabModels[x]`, as in, make one giant form instead of one form per tab? Note that the forms are not nested.

Comment: `Is there a way to do this, or should I submit the entire Model instead of Model.TabModels[x]`,Do you mean you want to bind the whole data inside for loop to action parameter when submitting the form.

Comment: @YiyiYou I mean use one form for the whole page instead of one per tab. I would prefer to have one form per tab, and only submit the form whose submit button is pressed.